# Run computation in separate process and kill it after a time limit

Tags: evaluation, kernel, external-calls

I am looking for a solution to run a Mathematica calculation in a separate process (separate kernel) and cancel the computation after a given time. If it cannot be cancelled, then just kill that process gracefully.

There are two easy ways to evaluate code in a separate kernel: parallel kernels and [`LocalSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalSubmit.html). What I am looking for is a mechanism to gracefully kill the kernel after a timeout if a soft-abort does not work.

The SageMath system has a feature like this: see [`@fork`](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/parallel/sage/parallel/decorate.html).

Comment: There are ways I can think of to do this, but they would all require me to re-implement the inter-kernel communication myself, which is a lot of work. I posted this question to see if there are some built-in ways that are simpler and what I missed.

Comment: You can be interested in: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5017071/590388), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5229294/590388).